# How to download and upload multiple artifacts to & from JFrog Artifactory using JFrog CLI

Tags: jfrog-cli

I would like to download multiple artifacts in one shot using jfrog rt dl command. I was able to download 1 file at a time. Can some body tell me, how I can specify multiple artifact paths to dl command.

And also while uploading, I would like to upload complete folder, which will have files and folders in it. How to upload with same folder structure.

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In general the solution depends on which artifacts you want to download or upload.
If you simply want to download all files from a specific folder inside a repository you can simply do it as follows:

```
jfrog rt dl my-repo/path/to/folder path/to/local/directory
```

For upload you can use placeholders - This will upload all files from the current directory to a specific repository in Artifactory:

```
jfrog rt u "(*)" my-local-repo
```

In case you want more flexibility, I suggest using file specs and AQL queries.
Check this for examples:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory

Comment: I found out an option for my problem statement. Thank you.